# Text exceeds page

Tags: multicol

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{Thesis}  
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{vwcol}  
\begin{document} 
\newgeometry{left=3cm, right=4cm, top=0.1cm, bottom=0.1cm}
\footnotesize 
\thispagestyle{empty}
\null\vfil
\begin{vwcol}[widths={0.65,0.35},
sep=.6cm, justify=flush,rule=1pt,indent=1em] 
\textbf{Authors:} Bob Marley\\
\\
\textbf{Title:} Simulation and Analysis of Relaxing using Object Oriented Programming.\\
\\
\textbf{Department:} Jamaica\\
 \\
 \textbf{Summary(max. 2000 characters):} 
\vspace{200mm}\\
\textbf{Uni M-0064}\\
\\
\textbf{March 2015}
 \vspace{15mm}\\
\textbf{Project period:}\\
\\
  \\
 \textbf{ECTS:}\\
30
 \vspace{10mm}\\
 \textbf{Education:}\\
 Master of Science
 \vspace{5mm}\\
\textbf{Field:}\\
Theory
\vspace{5mm}\\
\textbf{Supervisors:}\\
 Bob Dylan
\vspace{4mm}\\
 \textbf{Remarks:}\\
 This report is submitted as partial fulfillment of the requirements for graduation in the above education at the Technical University of Jamaica
\vspace{1mm}\\
\textbf{Contract no.:}\\
\vspace{5mm}\\
\textbf{Project no.:}\\
\vspace{5mm}\\
 \textbf{Sponsorship:}\\
  \vspace{1mm}\\
  \textbf{Front page:}\\
  \vspace{1mm}\\
  \textbf{Pages:}\\
   \textbf{Tables:}\\
\textbf{References:}\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\textbf{Technical University of Jamaica}\\
  Department of Computer science\\
  Freder 399\\
   Building 118\\
   4200 Neverland\\
   Jamaica\\
   Telephone +2323232323\\
   \\
   info@lol.uni.us\\
    www.lol.uni.us
   \end{vwcol} 
   \restoregeometry
    \end{document}
```

which produces the following result (without the red box):
[image]

It can be seen that the text goes out of the paper.Why is this happening.Cant find a solution.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you have uploaded the correct 'MWE'. Apart from shifted text area I don't see the effect you described ;-)

Comment: I copy paste my code here to be sure, and i still have this problem.

Comment: Do you have a recent TeX distribution, i.e. a recently updated `TeXLive` or `MikTeX` version?

Comment: I am using MikTex 2.9 and the latex editor i use is TexMaker 4.2

Comment: Well, quite recent, but I can't reproduce your 'error' with my (daily) updated TeXLive 2014

Comment: Where is the `Thesis.cls` you're using available?

Comment: I haven't isolated the exact cause yet, but you need to lighten up on the \\.  Putting in the occasional blank line does wonders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an attempt using a `tabularx`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}   %% showframe just for demo, remove
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{left=3cm, right=4cm, top=0.1cm, bottom=0.1cm}
\footnotesize
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}p{0.65\textwidth}!{\vrule width1pt}X@{}}
\textbf{Authors:} Bob Marley
&\textbf{Uni M-0064}\\[\baselineskip]
\textbf{Title:} Simulation and Analysis of Relaxing using Object Oriented Programming.
& \textbf{March 2015}\\[15mm]
\textbf{Department:} Jamaica & \\
 \textbf{Summary(max. 2000 characters):}
& \textbf{Project period:}\\[1cm]
&  \textbf{ECTS:}\\
 & 30\\[10mm]\\
& \textbf{Education:}\\
& Master of Science\\[5mm]\\
& \textbf{Field:}\\
& Theory\\[5mm]
& \textbf{Supervisors:}\\
&  Bob Dylan \\[4mm]
& \textbf{Remarks:}\\
& This report is submitted as partial fulfillment of the requirements for graduation in the above education at the Technical University of Jamaica\\[1mm]
&\textbf{Contract no.:}\\[5mm]
& \textbf{Project no.:}\\[5mm]
& \textbf{Sponsorship:}\\[1mm]
& \textbf{Front page:}\\[1mm]
&  \textbf{Pages:}\\
&   \textbf{Tables:}\\
&\textbf{References:}\\
&\\
&\\
&\\
&\\
&\\
&\\
&\textbf{Technical University of Jamaica}\\
&  Department of Computer science\\
&  Freder 399\\
&   Building 118\\
&   4200 Neverland\\
 &  Jamaica\\
&   Telephone +2323232323\\
&   \\
&   info@lol.uni.us\\
&    www.lol.uni.us
   \end{tabularx}
\vfill
    \end{document}
```

[image]